# How can I embed http referrer in divi contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

How can I embed http referrer in divi contact forms. I am able send only email, message text fields which are given inbetween %%field id%%. In Divi documentation they given that we need to put field id in between %% like this %%field id%%. But I am unable to add the http referrer or page url. I saw source code like this 
"

```
            <label for="et_pb_contact_name_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="et_pb_contact_name_1" class="input" value="" name="et_pb_contact_name_1" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="input" data-original_id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </p><p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_1 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="email" data-type="email">


            <label for="et_pb_contact_email_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="et_pb_contact_email_1" class="input" value="" name="et_pb_contact_email_1" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="email" data-original_id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </p><p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_2 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="phone" data-type="input">


            <label for="et_pb_contact_phone_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="et_pb_contact_phone_1" class="input" value="" name="et_pb_contact_phone_1" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="input" data-original_id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Only numbers allowed.">
        </p><p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_3 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="message" data-type="text">


            <label for="et_pb_contact_message_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Message</label>
            <textarea name="et_pb_contact_message_1" id="et_pb_contact_message_1" class="et_pb_contact_message input" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="text" data-original_id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </p><p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_4 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="url" data-type="input">


            <label for="et_pb_contact_url_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">New Field</label>
            <input type="text" id="et_pb_contact_url_1" class="input" value="" name="et_pb_contact_url_1" data-required_mark="not_required" data-field_type="input" data-original_id="url" placeholder="New Field">
        </p>
                    <input type="hidden" value="et_contact_proccess" name="et_pb_contactform_submit_0">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="et_pb_contactform_validate_0" class="et_pb_contactform_validate_field" />
                    <div class="et_contact_bottom_container">

                        <button type="submit" class="et_pb_contact_submit et_pb_button">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted" name="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted" value="8b651527df" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/data-analytics/test" />
                </form>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact -->
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact_form_container -->
```

Clearly there is hidden field but I dont know how to embed in form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create new field and set `display: none` then just copy id of this input field.
Next create below divi code module and paste this

`<script> const newInput = document.querySelector('#et_pb_contact_oboz-nazwa_0'); newInput.setAttribute('value', document.title) </script>`

Where `et_pb_contact_oboz-nazwa_0` - is ID of input field. You have to choose yours

`document.title` - is a title of page

If you want get url of page change `document.title` to `window.location.href`

And of course set this new input field to be not required